# Is there a way to set scheduledTransferPeriod to less than one minute?

Tags: c#, logging, azure, azure-diagnostics

I'm trying to set up logging for Windows Azure service.
I used `nlog` as described [here](http://awkwardcoder.blogspot.com/2012/03/getting-nlog-working-with-azure-is-as.html) and got it working, but now I want to experiment with different settings etc. Currently my `diagnostics.wadcfg` looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<DiagnosticMonitorConfiguration configurationChangePollInterval="PT1M" overallQuotaInMB="4096" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ServiceHosting/2010/10/DiagnosticsConfiguration">
  <DiagnosticInfrastructureLogs />
  <Directories>
    <IISLogs container="wad-iis-logfiles" />
    <CrashDumps container="wad-crash-dumps" />
  </Directories>
  <Logs bufferQuotaInMB="1024" scheduledTransferPeriod="PT1M" scheduledTransferLogLevelFilter="Verbose" />
</DiagnosticMonitorConfiguration>
```

I found out that one minute is a minimum value for `scheduledTransferPeriod`. But it's extremely inconvenient for development purposes, because I have to wait a minute after every change I make in logging to test it. Is there a way to reduce this time? Or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you aren't doing anything wrong.  You can try adding PT10S or something similar, but I believe this will just get rounded to a minute.  The diagnostics agent on the instances flush the data out of their buffers into the storage accounts and I don't think they will do so in less than 1 minute intervals.  This may be frustrating for development or testing, but for real production runs setting things this low can have a significant impact on the performance of the machine.  The system wasn't designed to be pumping information over this quickly.

One option, since you use nlog, is to use a [target that writes directly to Windows Azure Table storage](http://www.kongsli.net/nblog/2012/01/05/nlog-writing-log-entries-to-azure-table-storage/).  Then as you do your testing you can look at the table for your values. Some folks do this for production as well rather than using the log transfer mechanism. Of course, you are trading a single transfer from time to time, to something that could be very chatty so make sure you think about the impact transaction and overhead wise of using this in production.  One upside of going straight to table storage is that if the instances go down while between the flush of data you don't run the risk of losing data that was in the buffer.

Comment: Nice answer! I tried PT5S and similar, but it indeed got rounded to 1 minute.
No, I'm not going to write directly to Azure table, but I really wonder how those instance buffers work and where is the info stored BEFORE it actually goes to Azure table. Any links on this, please? :)

Comment: The table data is buffered/stored locally on each instance in a folder, but the format isn't something you likely want to deal with. If you remote into a Cloud Service instance you can fined these files, but they aren't plain text files.  On a deployment you might find them at C:\Resources\Directory\{DeploymentID}.{RoleName}.DiagnosticStore\Monitor\Tables.  They are .tsf files. And messing with them may lead to issue with the data being transferred. You can also see them in the emulator if you dig into the local resources of an instance.

Comment: [Full Disclosure: I work for Cerebrata] If you just want a tool to constantly monitor your trace logs the Azure Management Studio can do that. It has a "live feed" feature to pull the data on an interval (1 minute is the lowest, so not quicker but more convenient). Other storage tools may also have this feature.

Comment: FYI, you can use AzureTools' table2csv functionality to convert the TSF files to CSV files - http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kwill/archive/2013/08/26/azuretools-the-diagnostic-utility-used-by-the-windows-azure-developer-support-team.aspx